# Default spinner is not crescent but lines for Android Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, android-spinner

I added ion-refresher in a Ionic 4 project like this :

```html
<ion-refresher slot="fixed">
    <ion-refresher-content></ion-refresher-content>
</ion-refresher>
```

But for Android platform the default spinner showing up is lines not crescent.

Answer (score 0):

you can specify the spinner shape you want just follow this [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/components/spinner/Spinner/#usage)

Comment: Thanks, Ali for the immediate response. But I want it for ion-refresher spinner.
And in my case the issue is ion-refresher-content is not taking up the spinner platform specific like crescent for Android as default.